# anchorOffset is an int rather than a long in WebKit (chrome and safari)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I have code such as:

```
var selObj = (window.getSelection && window.getSelection());
if ( selObj !== null && selObj.anchorOffset) {
  var off = selObj.anchorOffset;
```

As far as I know anchorOffset should be a long - it is indeed a long in firefox and IE. But in Webkit, if I have a large selection over 65K, it truncates - i.e. I'm getting an int.

Is this a bug? Is there something else that I can use instead as a workaround?

Thanks.

---

I'm adding a very simple page that shows the problem:

```
<body>
<label ondblclick="var selObj = (window.getSelection && window.getSelection()); alert(selObj.anchorOffset);">
really really long text here
...
...
..
at 65K it wrpas around..
</label> 
</body>
```

If you replace the .... with a lot of text (over 65K characters) and open the page in chrome or safari and double click past the 65K mark you'll see it counts it as if it overflows.

It's as if there are multiple selections - but I have no clue how to get how many times it "wrapped around"

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript only has one number type (which is an IEEE-754 compliant floating-point double), so the difference you're seeing is probably an implementation difference in `window.getSelection()`.

Possible workarounds depend on the concrete use-case.

Comment: thanks. I'm in a <label> which as a lengthy string and is is inside a <div>. Upon a double-click even in the label I want to know what the user selected (from a lengthy test) so I use the anchoroffset to know what index in the string they are.

Comment: @DaveWilkin Sorry, I was unable to figure this out - the only thing I can think of is splitting the text in chunks of 65535 chars and creating separate elements for them. Then you can calculate the full selection offset by multiplying with the appropriate element index.